# After one minute onClickListener is not working alert dialog

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog

Can anyone help me?

```
private class ErrorDialogListener extends ErrorModalDialogListener {
    @Override
    public void onRetry() {

        startRequestIfNeed();
        super.onRetry();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        super.onCancel();
    }
}
```

When I'm waiting 1+ minute, on dialog's retry button click ErrorDialogListener isn't working.... Why?

Comment: post your  startRequestIfNeed() method code

Comment: it working with restApi request more classes I cant post all of them